# Elasticsearch query error in percolate query in ES

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

I am use the percolate query in ES. But I don't merge bool query and sort query:

**My purpose**:
Sort prices of added product today.

**My existing index**

```
        PUT /product-alert
        {
            "mappings": {
                "doctype": {
                    "properties": {
                        "product_name":    { "type": "text"  }, 
                        "price": { "type": "double"},
                        "user_id":      { "type": "integer" },
                        "date" : { "type": "date" }
                    }
                },
                "queries": {
                    "properties": {
                        "query": {
                            "type": "percolator"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have a following error.

```
  {
    "error": {
      "root_cause": [
        {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "mapper [sort] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"
        }
      ],
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "mapper [sort] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"
    },
    "status": 400
  }
```

Elastic query:

```
    PUT /product-alert/queries/1?refresh
    {
          "query": {
              "bool": {
                  "must": [
                      {
                          "query_string": {
                              "query": "(product_name:iphone)"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "range": {
                              "created_at": {
                                  "gte": "2017-05-12",
                                  "lte": "2017-05-12",
                                  "include_lower": true,
                                  "include_upper": true
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              }
          },
          "from": 0,
          "size": 200,
          "sort": [
              {
                  "price": {
                      "order": "asc"
                  }
              },
              "_score"
          ]
    }
```

Where is my fault? Sort working 'sort':'_score' only, but it is mischievous to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure, you need a percolator for that? It just seems like a normal query to me, I don't see the purpose of doing this as a percolator.

Comment: I added my index and mapping now. Please review again you

Comment: I honestly have never tried to sort percolator results, so I'm not sure. But I am relatively certain that it's not possible to store the sorting together with the query. Using a function score query to wrap your query string query and calculate the score in there (via script) might work. Yet still, I don't understand your purpose. To get sorted prices of todays products, you can just post that whole thing to '/doctype/_search'. no?

Comment: No, it is mischievous to me. I want to sort the prices of the selected products, not the whole day, actually.